# Type: PDOException Message: could not find driver

Tags: php, codeigniter, types, message

```
 $dbName = base_url('Upload/UPLOAD.MDB');
 $dbAccess = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; 
 DBQ=".$dbName."; Uid=; Pwd=;");
```

here's my code, I'm having trouble, I'm using php codeingiter. Thanks

Comment: make sure you have ODBC extension is there.

Comment: @varuog hmm, honestly this is my first time going to use ms access as database for codeigniter.. can you walk me through on how to properly connect.

Comment: check your php instllation dir. under ext dir you should have something like php_odbc.dll also make open php.ini and find extension php_odbc.dll and make sure it is enabled. you can also use phpinfo() to see if it is enabled or not.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php